# Table getting out of fieldset border in Firefox only

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form where i have fieldsets, in 1 fieldset i have a table. This table will be in the fieldset in chrome and IE but not in Firefox. Please have a look:

https://jsfiddle.net/79504g5b/1/

my fieldset has this CSS:

```
#msform fieldset {
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 20px 30px;

  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;

  /*----------------------->2*/ position: absolute;

}
```

I don't know what is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element `.statusHead1` does not occupy the available width. So, `table` is added next to it, in the available space.

To move `table` on it's own line, use `clear: both` on the `table`.

```
table {
    clear: both;
}
```

See [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/79504g5b/2/).

Optionally, you can also set the `float: left` to the `table`.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/79504g5b/3/)

I'll recommend you to use `clear: both`. Using this, you don't have to change your other elements structure/view.

Comment: As I see (from @Anandh SP's answer) I could also remove the float:left from .statusHead1 what would be best to do

Comment: @bboni Depends on your html structure

Comment: @bboni If you want any element on the right side of `.statusHead1`, you'll need `float: left` on it. If you don't, then you can remove `float: left`;

Answer (score 1):

Remove float:left form .statusHead1 class

Check this link https://jsfiddle.net/g0t1rwyw/

```
.statusHead1{
    /*float:left;*/
    width: 600px;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-bottom:1px solid #bfcfdf;
}
```